# Differences on modifier keys between US and International Keyboards

Tags: keyboard, hardware, internationalization

I'm aware of the differences in layout, character placement etc however I have always wondered why the modifier keys on the US layout use the full word such as <kbd>command</kbd> instead of <kbd>cmd</kbd>. Similarly the same can be seen for <kbd>function</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>.

Any idea why? The only reason I could think of is that the abbreviations suit various languages, whereas the full word e.g. `function` as opposed to `funktion` in German would be wrong but `fn` makes sense in both.

[image: Keyboard Comparison]

Comment: Perhaps it is because the keys are smaller that the words have been abbreviated?

Comment: Yes that could be a reason, but on MacBooks which have the function key on the left for both layouts unlike above the same abbreviation exists as well as the full word on the US version.

Comment: You can see them all at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794